# cat /dev/ttyUSB - Why does this work, also why doesn't it work

Tags: linux, debian, cat, tty

I have an devive blasting some data continiously into an FTDI that's connected to my PC over USB. I want to log the data into a CSV using a simple bash script.

When I cat /dev/ttyUSB0 I'm getting some characters that I want (1023) and also some malformed random character.

1. How does the phy reciving the data know the baud rate?
2. Where are the malformed packets coming from?

Running: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit

[Screencap of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F1Ey.png)

Answer (score 2):

1. You can set the baud rate using `stty`. For example to set the baudrate to 9600 do:

   ```
   stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 9600
   ```
2. This could because ground has not been connected between the devices. Loose connections. Noise if you use long serial wires. There could be many reasons.

Comment: Cool, that's an awesome trick. Contact is fine, because when I read the data using screen or minicom it's okay. I ended up using screen's logging function (-L) Thanks for the help!